# LinearLayout - adding a TableLayout after a TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with LinearLayout where I want to display a TableLayout after a TextView. I've tried modifying the LayoutParams however I can't seem to make it wrap (which I'm assuming I want it to do).

This is simplified version:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
sv.removeAllViews();

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
sv.addView(ll);

//This is displayed
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Hello World");
ll.addView(tv);

//This is not displayed - but if I remove the above view it will display...
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
ll.addView(tl, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Why are you creating the layout programmatically instead of defining it in XML?

Comment: its part of an exercise.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code you're using (non-simplified version) and xml layout in which the `ScrollView` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

By specifiying Orientation as Vertical it worked for me:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
sv.removeAllViews();

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Hello World");
ll.addView(tv);

TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
ll.addView(tl);
```